# Clarification of components and efficiency of animation method

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I looked at the Apple documentation for animations, and most of it seems pretty clear. However, I'm going to explain animations to a group of people soon, and there are some components of the animation method that I don't quite understand. Here's the code that I took off of the documentation:

```
- (IBAction)showHideView:(id)sender
{
    // Fade out the view right away
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
        delay: 0.0
        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
        animations:^{
             thirdView.alpha = 0.0;
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            // Wait one second and then fade in the view
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 delay: 1.0
                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                    thirdView.alpha = 1.0;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
        }];
}
```

For one, I'm wanting to know if this block-based process is better to use versus the begin/commit process.

My other questions regard the arrow(^) before each method within the block of code and the use of the UIViewAnimationOption.

Why is the arrow needed before each sub-method?

Is a UIViewAnimationOption just a primitive, or is it something that is automatically returning a value?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers to most of your questions can be found simply by looking at the UIView documentation.

From the docs:

**Use of the methods in this (the begin/commit) section is discouraged in iOS 4 and later. Use the block-based animation methods instead.**

The same document lists `UIViewAnimationOptions` as `typedef NSUInteger UIViewAnimationOptions;` NSUInteger is basically just a typedef for a standard unsigned int.

The caret (^) syntax is used to denote a block.

Comment: Thanks. As great as the Apple documentation is, I find user verification to be more reassuring.